# Spring Mail with Freemarker Templates from Database

Tags: java, database, spring, freemarker

I am a newbie to adding Freemarker to Spring and Spring Mail.  I am not using Spring Boot, but I am using the latest Spring 4.x, and though we have an application context XML file, we do use annotations.

So, ultimately I want to read the templates out of a database, because we may have many of them for many clients.   We will not be loading templates from a filename or from disk.

We have our Spring Application as a maven multi-module project:

```
entity.jar - module
dao.jar - module
services.jar - module
ws.jar - module
```

Under services we have an application context file that defines Freemarker as follow:

```
 <bean id="freemarkerConfiguration"
        class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
        <property name="preTemplateLoaders">
            <list>
                <ref bean="databaseTemplateLoader" />
            </list>
        </property>
      </bean>

      <bean name="databaseTemplateLoader" 
       class="com.myapp.server.util.DatabaseToFreeMarkerTemplateLoader" />
```

I have a new class called:

```
  public class DatabaseToFreeMarkerTemplateLoader extends StringTemplateLoader
     {
        // todo: add code here
     }
```

But I am not sure what else I need in here.   I am looking on the internet for some examples, but I can't find too much.

If someone can point me to an example, or refer me to another link here, I'll do my best to see if I can literally fill in the blanks.

Thanks!

BTW: I am surprised I had to include spring-web in my services layer in order to make this work.   I just wanted to format an email and not html pages.   So if there a better formatting tool that works seamlessly with Spring, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this part of Spring much, but I don't think you need `spring-web`. You could just use the FreeMarker API directly both for configuring (i.e., create a `freemarker.template.Configuration` singleton bean) and generating the output (`template = configuration.getTemplate(...)`, `template.process(...)`). Finally you simply use `message.setText(theOutputFromTemplateDotProcess, true);` (where `message` is the Spring `MimeMessageHelper`). So there's no much to integrate with Spring here, I believe. (Even if someone needs to load templates from Spring resources, they can use an `org.springframework.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader` via `Configuration.setTemplateLoader`.)

As of using FreeMarker API directly (not related to Spring), see this example: http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_quickstart_all.html